# SQOL - MAX condition in left inner join

Tags: soql, aggregate

I am getting a syntax error but can't quite figure out what I have mistyped. Can anyone spot what I am missing?

```
Select ID,Name FROM Employees__c WHERE Account__r.Tag__c INCLUDES ('Inactive') AND ID IN
(Select Employee__c FROM Employee_Session__c HAVING MAX(Session_Date__c) < 2015-01-01)
```

Error message:
MALFORMED_QUERY: 
Employee__c FROM Employee_Session__c HAVING MAX(Session_Date__c) < 2015-01-01)
^
ERROR at Row:2:Column:45
expecting a right parentheses, found 'HAVING'

Comment: HAVING only works with the GROUP BY clause, and I don't think you can use Group By in an inner join.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should just be able to use a `WHERE` clause in your join:

```
Id IN (
    SELECT Lookup__c FROM Child__c WHERE Date_Field__c < 2015-01-01
)
```